# Angular2/4 - how to run NPM modules via Jenkins?

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, npm-install, node-modules

We are using Angular4 and trying to perform a build using Jenkins (Windows Server).

While running the scripts we need, for example: ngc with a regular user/admin everything is ok.

While trying running it using Jenkins (i assume it is running under system or network user?) nothing is running and Jenkins output is that 'NPM' is not installed etc..

What have we missed?

Thanks!